# Why does activator report invalid sha1 in Play 2.3.2 project?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am using Play Framework 2.3.2. Upon running `./activator` it ends with the following FAILED messages:

```
[info] downloading httpx://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-api;1.0-alpha-16!plexus-component-api.jar: invalid sha1: expected=5a2100a1c6a37804b1abfc70000b0ea33b83b7f9 computed=e66d6bb59e7a4c30070b1754fd8642fbd054cceb (366ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-component-api;1.0-alpha-16!plexus-component-api.jar: invalid sha1: expected=5a2100a1c6a37804b1abfc70000b0ea33b83b7f9 computed=e66d6bb59e7a4c30070b1754fd8642fbd054cceb (366ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   httpx://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.jar ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.codehaus.plexus#plexus-classworlds;1.2-alpha-7!plexus-classworlds.jar: invalid sha1: expected=ed03d1eeb9b2576747df0d2883d9006fa5e1febe computed=565d66455a99bdaf266b1fd4c4910f602f8f1333 (600ms)
```

I set `checksums := Nil` in global `build.sbt` already.

How could I fix the issues?

**Replay to @Jacek Laskowski**

I can download it manually behind a proxy.

wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar

```
[root@dwcds-twps1 ~]# jar -tf plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
org/
org/codehaus/
org/codehaus/plexus/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/composition/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/discovery/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/reloading/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/
org/codehaus/plexus/configuration/
org/codehaus/plexus/context/
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/
org/codehaus/plexus/component/composition/CompositionException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/discovery/ComponentDiscoveryEvent.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/discovery/ComponentDiscoveryListener.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/reloading/ComponentReloadingException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/reloading/ComponentReloadingStrategy.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/ComponentDependency.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/ComponentDescriptor.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/ComponentRequirement.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/ComponentSetDescriptor.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentConfigurationException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentDescriptorUnmarshallingException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentImplementationNotFoundException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentLifecycleException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentLookupException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentManagerImplementationNotFoundException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentProfileException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/component/repository/exception/ComponentRepositoryException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/configuration/PlexusConfiguration.class
org/codehaus/plexus/configuration/PlexusConfigurationException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/context/Context.class
org/codehaus/plexus/context/ContextException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/AbstractLogEnabled.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/AbstractLogger.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/AbstractLoggerManager.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/LogEnabled.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/Logger.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/LoggerManager$1.class
org/codehaus/plexus/logging/LoggerManager.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Configurable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Contextualizable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Disposable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Initializable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/InitializationException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Serviceable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/ServiceLocator.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Startable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/StartingException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/StoppingException.class
org/codehaus/plexus/personality/plexus/lifecycle/phase/Suspendable.class
org/codehaus/plexus/PlexusContainer$1.class
org/codehaus/plexus/PlexusContainer.class
org/codehaus/plexus/PlexusContainerException.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.codehaus.plexus/
META-INF/maven/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/
META-INF/maven/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-component-api/pom.properties
com/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/OkDialog.class
com/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/PolicyRuntime$ReportThread.class
com/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/CallContext.class
skip..............
```

Comment: Where did you get this `httpx` urls from? I dunno why activator might need `plexus-component-api`. Are you behind a proxy? Could you download the jar using the url and check its content with `jar -tf`?

Comment: I have no idea why activator need `plexus-component-api` .All of the jars failed to download with same error.